Problema en conexion en base de datos sql desde web.config Asp.net
**Hola Tengo un problema en conectarme a la base de datos en sql server, Estoy haciendo un sitio web con Asp.net y al momento de registrar el usuario tarda mucho en cargar y me arroja un mensaje de error en visual studio (lo dejo en las imágenes el tipo de error), cabe mencionar que ya aplique las configuraciones para que el SA pueda conectarse, o el error puede ser que mientras ejecuto el sitio desde mi pc y el sql server esta en mi laptop.
**




[


This question is similar to: Error al conectar SQL SERVER vía TCP/IP: Connect timed out. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Revisa esta respuesta, con eso seguro resuelves tu problema. Saludos.
